# Having two columns taking the full width but with a separator

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I am having the following html code :

```
<div class='col-sm-7 foo'>...</div>
<div class='col-sm-5 foo'>...</div>
```

and in my css:

```
.foo {
   background-color: white;
}
```

I can't add some margin between them as they are taking the full width due to bootstrap. Though I would like to add a separator between them (10px or so) with no background-color. How can I achieve this (I have to use bootstrap for other reasons).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the alignment of the col margins, and offset with padding:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11229/)

```
<div class='col-sm-7 foo'>...</div>
<div class='col-sm-5 foo'>...</div>


.foo {
    background-color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .foo:first-of-type {
        margin:0 5px 0 -5px;
        padding-left:20px;
    }
    .foo:last-of-type {
        margin:0 -5px 0 5px;
        padding-right:20px;
    }
}
body {
    background:black;
}
```

Comment: I thought about that as well, but can I with a border, remove the background-color ? (and not set a new one)

Answer (score 0):

Add another div width a col size of 1 and a width of 10px and no background. Change the column width of the others as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns have 15px padding by default, so could you wrap your `foo` class in a column?  For example:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
   <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
   <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

Then you have your `foo` divs with white background and 15px of padding (and no background color).

http://jsfiddle.net/3cz3zy3k/

Answer (score -2):

Just put your background color on a child of the column rather than the column itself. In my experience it's best to avoid modifying grid elements in general.

```
.foo {
    background-color: pink;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-xs-7'><div class='foo'>...</div></div>
        <div class='col-xs-5'><div class='foo'>...</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3cz3zy3k/2/)**